# Converting string to float using sscanf() gives slightly different results in C

Tags: c, string, floating-point, scanf, precision

I am taking numerical string as an input from user and than converting it to float with the help of `sscanf()` function :

```
#include<stdio.h>

float getfloat(void);

int main()
{
    float a;
    a=getfloat();
    printf("You entered %f\n",a);
    return 0;
}

float getfloat(void)
{
    float n;
    char nstr[50];
    printf("Enter a numeric string\n");
    gets(nstr);
    sscanf(nstr,"%f",&n);
    return n;
}
```

Now let's suppose I enter a string `100.1234`. After converting to float with help of `sscanf` when i print the float value i am getting `100.123398` as stored value. Now these are very close values but why am i not getting the same result as i entered. What is going on inside `sscanf` ?

Comment: The problem is not sscanf but floating point see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6865932)

Comment: I also suggest [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6865932) for `gets`.

Comment: As an alternative to `gets`, use [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), i.e. `fgets(nstr, 50, stdin);`

Comment: You won't get `100.123398` printed because your `getfloat()` returns `int`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit this here. I meant float only. I have changed it appropriately.

Comment: @LocalHost, yes that's it, and to fix you problem, use `double` instead of `float`, don't forget the correct specifier `%lf`.